# Manually Invoke a Controller's Action in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I invoke (or get the result of said invokation) a controllers action given I have the `HttpMethod`, `Path`, `Headers` and any post `Data` as strings in a websocket listener of an asp.net core webapi project?

I Have a asp.net core webapi project and I want to add websocket functionality. 
I want to be able to "call" the http api endpoints via the websockets. In order to do that i have defined a custom message that contains the `HttpMethod`, `Path`, `Headers` and any post `Data`. 
In order to try the approach I am currently creating an HttpClient and "forwarding" the request to the correct endpoint and it works but I would like to do this internally.

Comment: Have you looked into SignalR?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find a way to invoke a controller's action from signalR